# Newt got 3 points to Hufflepuff. What Hogwarts points awards or deductions were not in multiples of 5?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

From trailer: 3 points to Hufflepuff.

1. Where there any else in movies or books (including cursed child and fantastic beasts)?

How about games? As for games, I can't remember any in the games I played, but I guess anything's possible in some games.

According to [fandom](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/House_points), it's just those 1 point deductions in 1991.

2. Were there any prime number points awarded except 3 or 5 points?

Note: This may include cases where say there were deductions made in, say, percentages like deducting 0.5% of total house points or something.

Comment: When I saw the trailer, I assumed Dumbledore is just joking. Newt is already an adult and presumably isn't enrolled in Hogwarts as a student anymore.

Comment: @RobertColumbia oh yeah lol thanks. well i guess alumni/dropouts can't earn points for the house/s they were in. / Newt hought (intentional mispelling. and again): part of the joke is that hogwarts points are always given in multiples of 5. the only flaw in this understanding of the joke are those 1 point deductions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Points are usually in groups of five or ten, but not always, as evidenced Harry losing single points for "cheek" (twice).

> There was a sudden rummaging for quills and parchment. Over the noise,
> Snape said, ‘And a point will be taken from Gryffindor house for your
> cheek, Potter.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone: The Potion Master</sup></sub>

More importantly, we see that other houses have gained (or lost) point scores in multiples other than five.

> ‘Now, as I understand it, the House Cup here needs awarding and the
> points stand thus: in fourth place, Gryffindor, with three hundred and
> **twelve** points; in third, Hufflepuff, with three hundred and fifty-**two**;
> Ravenclaw have four hundred and twenty-**six** and Slytherin, four hundred
> and seventy-**two**.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone: The Man with Two Faces</sup></sub>

The Lexicon does note that in [every other book](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/house-points/), that points are exclusively awarded in the following amounts; 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 and 200.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot about those house cup totals. nice. thanks Valorum !